# Escape and sanitize $_GET parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, get, htmlspecialchars

I know data should be sanitized when it is being outputted or displayed, NOT when it's being received or stored. This is what I'm doing now:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES);
```

If I'm going to get the $_GET parameters and check the database for them, should I still sanitize and escape? For example:

```
$name = htmlspecialchars($_GET['name'], ENT_QUOTES);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = :name");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->execute();
```

So is `htmlspecialchars` needed or should I just do `$name = $_GET['name']`?

Comment: Only if it's stored in that same state.  You're essentially modifying data before comparing it with stored data.  If the stored data hasn't been likewise modified, it won't match.

Comment: Handle 'safe data' rules consistently *at the usage site* - eg. as used in the HTML. It doesn't matter if this comes from the GET directly or indirectly (via the DB).

Answer (score 3):

PDO makes it even easier than you've done:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = :name");
$stmt->execute([ 'name' => $_GET['name'] ]);
```

That's it. Done.

It's important that you **do not** escape things when using placeholder values, especially when doing matching. `htmlspecialchars` is *only* relevant in an HTML context, outside of that it causes damage. If you're showing data in JSON, in an email, or wherever, escape for that context and that context *only*.

If someone has a name like "A&W" then when you search you'll mangle the input and actually search for "A&amp;W" which is not what their name is. They'll get zero matches and then they'll ask you what's wrong with your site.

The *only* thing you should do with input data is trim out any characters that might interfere with the search matching, like leading and trailing spaces someone may have introduced *accidentally*.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `htmlspecialchars()`.  `bind()` does all the escaping and quoting that you need.

PHP has a confusing array of escapers --

- urlencode - when building a value for a URL.
- htmlentities, htmlspecialcharacters - for `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<a>` -- escapes only `"&<>`
- nl2br (or `<pre>`) - for dealing with line endings
- mysql_real_escape_string - Do not use the `mysql*` routines.
- mysqli_real_escape_string - when escaping in `mysqli*` routines -- at least `'"\`
- addslashes - almost as good as the above
- hex, base64_encode - possible kludges for dealing with non-text

What is *usually* best when storing text into a MySQL table, is to escape the string only enough to get past the parser.  This escaping vanishes as the processing occurs.  Leave the accented characters, etc alone.

- apostrophe and double quote -- these indicate the end of the string, so you need to escape them somehow.
- backslash -- the tradition escaper.  But then what if you want a backslash?

PHP's PDO and mysqli have ways of "binding" that do all the work for you.  If, instead, you use PHP's "interpolation", such as

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM t WHERE x = {$_GET['x']}";
```

you get no escaping and no SQL-injection protection.  *Do not write code that way unless you have somehow already checked the args.*

For HTML, you need a different set of escapers.  Think about the `<`.  This introduces a tag.  So how do you display a "less-than"?  Well, you need the "html entity" for it:  `&lt;`.  That then leads to `&` being problematic; hence `&amp;`.

Comment: I'd say do not write that kind of SQL period, even *if* you have checked the args. There are ways of injecting things that can bypass escaping under some circumstances. Keeping data and query fully separated is the only guaranteed safe way.

Answer (score 1):

> So is htmlspecialchars needed or should I just do $name =
>   $_GET['name']?

No, it's not needed.

Keep the input data *as is*, agnostic to output medium. It should not be *prepared* for safe HTML embedding.

What if tomorrow you'll need this data in JSON format for some API, PDF or a desktop app?

Answer (score 0):

You should still be *validating* the input for data integrity purposes, eg: making sure that the input is more or less what you expect for the sake of your application's stability. However, since you're using prepared statements you don't have any pressing need to "sanitize" [aka "corrupt"] your data as it is being more stringently encapsulated by the database driver.

`htmlspecialchars()` makes the data safe for inclusion in an HTML document, and should only be used when you're outputting the data into an HTML document. Doing this before inserting into the database is more or less polluting your data for use in anything *other* than an HTML document.